# Accept call then play a pre-recorded voice message to caller

Tags: calls, voicemail

I receive quite a few non-work calls during my working day that often I am unable to take. I am not a big fan of voicemail, and I would much prefer if the caller would send me an SMS message or an email instead. I would therefore like to do the following on my Android phone:

- disable my carrier's voicemail
- record a voice message to a sound file
- when my phone rings have an app automatically accept the call after X rings (or seconds), then;
- play back the sound file to the caller, then;
- hang up

Is there a way to achieve this? Perhaps an app?

Comment: If you're in the USA, you might want to take a look at YouMail or other visual voicemail apps

Comment: I'm in the UK...

Comment: I think YouMail is available in the UK. However, to be sure, try installing it from the a Play store and if you can't, I guess it's not available there. You might want to look here to find an app that works in the UK: http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-os-apps-f35/best-visual-voicemail-youmail-vs-hullomail-vs-googlevoice-412808/

Comment: that can not be done with android SDK. you need a special ROM and platform. I have did a product for convert IP call to telcom call in QCom MSM7227A platform

Comment: This can be done via Tasker

Comment: @user218076 pl elaborate how

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible. There is no API for that. The [MediaPlayer API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) docs say:

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US you can create get a Google Voice number and place callers into groups.  A group can have a customized announcement and do not disturb.  GV  is free and you can have GV ring multiple phones such as home, office and cellphone.

If you install  Groove you can have it first and ring your GV number and directly or indirectly other phones.

If someone sends an SMS message to your GV number or your direct.to (GrooVe) number it will send you an email message.