# Is there any app that can accept incoming calls and play a voice message using Text To Speech?

Tags: applications, calls, text-to-speech, auto-answer

I used to use an app that could do exactly that. When a person would call, the app would accept the call, enable the loudspeaker, and play a voice message aloud using text-to-speech. Meaning, the app would accept the call, enable the loudspeaker, and play a voice message aloud from the phone's speaker.

As the call would be on loudspeaker, the caller would be able to hear everything that was being said. The call would end when the caller (or the receiver) would hang up. If no one hung up, the call would continue indefinitely after the message was read aloud. The app was completely free.

Unfortunately, I cannot find that app now. Does it still exist? If not, is there any other app similar to it available currently?

Comment: Any decent hands-free driving app should do this.  Try Ultimate Car Dock.  OTOH, this is probably off-topic

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: Related, though maybe not answering the question fully: [Accept call then play a pre-recorded voice message to caller](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/77846/44325), [How to use Tasker to answer a private number, play an audio file to the caller and hang up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/104804/44325)